# How to executed an radio onchange event based another event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, radio-button, onchange

I have several radio button inside a table.

```
<table id='t_test'>
<tr>
   <td><input type='radio' id='radio1' value='0' class='form-control' /></td>
   <td><input type='radio' id='radio2' value='50' class='form-control' /></td>
   <td><input type='radio' id='radio3' value='100' class='form-control' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type='button' id='btn_radio' />
```

I have an `onchange` event on these radio buttons.

```
$("#t_test").on('change','input[type=radio]',function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

How to trigger above `onchange` event on another event? I have this button click event.

```
$('#btn_radio').on('click', function(){
     var i = 50;

     if(i == 0){
        $("#radio1").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
    }
    else if(i == 50){
        $("#radio2").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
    }
    else if(i == 100){
        $("#radio3").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
    }       
    else{
        alert("Error Occured");
    }


});
```

So, when I click the button, The radio which id is `radio2` is checked and the alert is fired.

Comment: Your code works fine. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g5oeakhb/).

Comment: It's the button ID.

Comment: But, why the radio alert is not fired?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The alert is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

Add name to your button.

And of course the is no alert after checked. It's because when all the radio has been checked. There is no more change trigger, except for click trigger.

Or you don't want this radio in group(same name)?

```
<table id='t_test'>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='radio' name='radio' id='radio1' value='0' class='form-control' /></td>
    <td><input type='radio' name='radio' id='radio2' value='50' class='form-control' /></td>
    <td><input type='radio' name='radio' id='radio3' value='100' class='form-control' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type='button' id='btn_radio' />
```